# Highchart multiple lines in line graph with more points takes 30sec to Display

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts in vaadin application . It works in a best manner for single line graph.
If i put 49 lines and each lines contain 2048 values . I have disabled the marker , shadow,
tooltip,animation . But still the graph takes 30 seconds to display in google chrome and more than 30 seconds in firefox. How to display in a fast manner .The code is given below

```
String s = "";
s+="chart = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);"+
                "  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({\n" + 
                "            chart: {\n" + 
                "                renderTo: 'container5',\n" + 
                "                type: 'line',\n" +                 
                "            },\n" + 
                "            title: {\n" + 
                "                text: 'Intensity Graph'\n" + 
                "            },\n" +
                "            xAxis: {\n" + 
                "            min:0,\n"+
                "            max:2100,\n"+
                "            tickInterval:100,\n"+
                "                labels: {\n" + 
                "                    rotation: -45,\n" + 
                "                    align: 'right',\n" + 
                "                    style: {\n" + 
                "                        fontSize: '13px',\n" + 
                "                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'\n" + 
                "                    }\n" + 
                "                }\n" + 
                "            },\n" + 
                "        yAxis: {\n" + 
                "           title:{\n" + 
                "            text:''\n" +               
                "           },"+                
                "             min:0,\n"+
                "             max:255,\n"+  
                "            tickInterval:20,\n"+
                "        },\n" + 
                "plotOptions: {\n" + 
                "            series: {\n" + 
                "                marker: {\n" + 
                "                    enabled: false,\n" +                   
                "                    shadow : false,\n"+
                "                    animation : false\n"+              
                "            },"+
                "color: '#00FF00',\n"+
                "            lineWidth: 0.1"+   
                "           },"+            
                "        },"+
                " tooltip: {\n" + 
                "            enabled: false\n" + 
                "        },"+
                "            legend: {\n" + 
                "                enabled: false\n" + 
                "            },\n" + 
//              "            tooltip: {\n" + 
//              "                formatter: function() {\n" + 
//              "                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+\n" + 
//              "                        'lux: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +\n" + 
//              "                        ' px';\n" + 
//              "                }\n" + 
//              "            },\n" + 
                "                series: [{\n" + 
                "                name: 'Ejection Count',\n" + 
                "                data: [" +
                "],\n" + 
                "                dataLabels: {\n" + 
                "                    enabled: true,\n" + 
                "                    rotation: -90,\n" + 
                "                    color: '#FFFFFF',\n" + 
                "                    align: 'right',\n" + 
                "                    x: -3,\n" + 
                "                    y: 10,\n" + 
                "                    formatter: function() {\n" + 
                "                        return this.y;\n" + 
                "                    },\n" + 
                "                    style: {\n" + 
                "                        fontSize: '13px',\n" + 
                "                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'\n" + 
                "                    }\n" + 
                "                }\n" + 
                "            }]\n" + 
                "        });" +             
                "  });");

long len = 2,kk1 = 0;
            Highchart hc = new Highchart();
            byte[] cor = new byte[4584];// I am adding this array content to the graph
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try
            {
                for (long l = 0; l < len; l++) 
                {
                    sb.append(" this.chart.addSeries({\n" + 
                    "            data: [" );    
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
                {                   
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                        //2048 points
                            for (int j = 0,k = 276; k < 2324; j++,k++) 
                        {
                                    if(j == 2323)
                            {   
                              sb.append(cor[k]) ;
                            }                           
                            else 
                            {
                              sb.append((cor[k] +",");
                            }
                        }
                        }                      
                }
                    sb.append("],"+
                    "     redraw :false,\n"+
                    "     animation:false\n"+
                    "});") ;                                        
                }   
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sb.append("this.chart.redraw();");  
                        hc.drawChart(sb.toString());

                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use one of wrappers for Java? http://www.highcharts.com/download

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts are not so fast to display 100k points. For that purpose I advice to use Highstock, see example with 54k points: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping where charts are build within 0.2 sec. The main speed up in Highstock is [dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).